# What's best solution for multi store?

Tags: paypal, express, integration

what's best paypal integration way for more than 3 store ?

we need to integrate paypal, with same account, to 3 different store (not same products)

could be made this with paypal express ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should call paypal for this question.  They have a whole support team to answer these type of questions.

The short answer is yes, as long as the paypal expresss account doesn't limit the number of sites.

I've used paypal multiple times for online shopping carts and I'm pretty sure there's no limitation to the number of sites you can use your account for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the PayPal services for this, they all allow you to set the payment service up on more than one website.  Just keep in mind that all of the payments will flow into one account, so if you need to be able to sort the payments in your account or download history you would need to sort them on your end.  Some merchants have used different method for this, such as passing item id's over with each item or invoice id's with each transaction and have the first site pass the invoice id's over but have them start with A, and the second site would have B for the first letter of the invoice id.  There are several different ways you can do this.

Comment: Thanks 
We need to receive confirmation of payment to different store (with idn or other), so need to paypal flow that permit us to send the return url for validate payment